# DELETE user Express side works, but can't make it work on front-end side (using React)

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I created my route users/delete on server side (Express), which I tested via Postman and works without any issue, but somehow I can not make it work on front-end side.

This is my react code, where I am trying to create function of deleting and fetching route from express by using axios :

```
  const handleDelete = () => {
    axios
      .delete("http://localhost:9090/users/delete", {})
      .then(response => response.data)
      .catch(error => {
        throw error.response.data;
      });
  };
```

And here is how I am using the function :

```
  <button type="button" onClick={handleDelete}>
    Delete your account
  </button>
</div>
```

I am still new in this tech, so I am not sure about what is the right way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You should make your backend (express) delete route like this: `/users/:userId`.

A user id is needed to delete a certain user.

Then you can do this in frontend:

```
async function deleteUser(userId) {
  try {
    const request = await axios.delete(`http://localhost:9090/users/${userId}`)
    console.log("deleted")
  } catch(err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}
```

Your controller:

```
router.delete("/users/delete/:userId", isAuthenticated, async (req, res, next) => {
    const { userId } = req.params
    try {
        const user = await User.query().findById(userId).throwIfNotFound()
        await user.$query().delete()
        res.json(user)
    } catch (err) {
        next(err)
    }
})
```

Comment: When I add /:userId to my route, my server side is not working. Do I need to define it somewhere first ?

Comment: @Petra you need to add /:userId on your route, then select it on your controller like this:
const { userId } = req.params

Comment: This is how my route looks like now : `router.delete(
  "/users/delete/:userId",
  isAuthenticated,
  async (req, res, next) => {
    const { userId } = req.params;
    try {
      const user = await User.query()
        .findById(id)
        .throwIfNotFound();
      await user.$query().delete();
      res.json(user);
    } catch (err) {
      next(err);
    }
  }
);` //// It is printing out only [Object object] in my server terminal

Comment: @Petra I updated my answer. You weren't using the userId variable.

Comment: I updated everything like you posted now - I am having 403 error though, and now not even server side works in Postman

Comment: @Petra are you making the request properly? It should be a delete to: `/users/user_id_to_delete`

Comment: @Gramper I am not sure, I am getting really lost in that. :(

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the comments, I believe the issue might be with the `isAuthenticated` middleware you are using, as when Authentication middleware fails it throws `403 Forbidden` error.
You might need to pass some token which will authenticate your request in the `axios` call.

```
const request = await axios.delete(`http://localhost:9090/users/${userId}`,{header})
```

If you can provide more info on the middleware, I'll update my answer.

Comment: this is **The middleware :** const isAuthenticated = (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    if (req.session.user) {
      next();
    } else throw res.status(403);
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
};

module.exports = { isAuthenticated };

Comment: So as you can see you are receiving 403 from here, so you need to pass  `user` via headers, if stored in cookies you can use 

`const request = await axios.delete(http://localhost:9090/users/${userId},{withCredentials: true})`

Comment: I tried, and seems like it solved 403 error, but now i get 404, which I dont understand, since user is logged in.